# No puedo cargar imagen con PHASER 3 - JS

Tags: javascript, phaser3

phaser 3 es un framework de js para hacer juegos, estoy intentado cargar una imagen, pero me sale un cuadro verde, he buscado y dicen que puede ser problemas de ruta pero tengo mis rutas bien y aun asi sale el cuadro verde,

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

aqui el codigo:

```
class Scene extends Phaser.Scene {

    constructor() {
        super("Scene");  //constructor gives name to scene
    }
    prelaod () {
        this.load.image("space","img/NY.jpg");
    }
    create() {
        //this.background.setOrigin(0,0);
        this.add.text(20,20,"Loading...");
        this.scene.start("Scene2");
    }
}

class Scene2 extends Phaser.Scene {

    constructor() {
        super("Scene2");
    }

    create() {
        this.add.image(50,50,"space");
        //this.background.setOrigin(0,0);
        this.add.text(20,20,"Welcome to scene 2");
        //this.input.on("pointerdown", () => this.scene.start("Scene"));
        
    }
}
```

hago el preload en la escena1 y luego al ir a la escena2, le agrego la imagen, pero aparece ese cuadro verde, cambie de png a jpg, pero tampoco funciona

Answer (score 0):

Es un error porque no estás corriendo tu juego en un servidor http sino con el protocolo file (doble click en tu index.html digamos), que tiene sus restricciones. Posibles soluciones: si estás usando visual studio usa el live preview. Si estás usando sublime podés usar el package browser sync. Sino en la misma página de phaser en la sección learn tienen un instructivo para montar un servidor local. Suerte!